# 正規表現を用いた、不規則な文字列からの数値の抽出

Tags: python

「徒歩分数」と「電車の乗車時間」が混在したデータがあります。
徒歩分数のみを取り出して、それ以外は欠損値とする、
新たなデータを作成したいと考えています。

```
y: [4, NaN, 5]
```

現在は「分」を取り除く所までですが、以下のようになっています。
どなたか、ご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['徒歩４分', '2駅12分', '約5分']},
    index=[1, 2, 3])

df["walk_time"] = df.x.str.extract(r'(\d*)分')
```

Comment: 「`約n分`は徒歩とみなす」で合っていますか？また、全角数字が含まれるケースも考慮の必要がありますか？

Comment: 説明が足らず、すいません。「約n分」は徒歩分数とみなし、index=1の場合のような、全角数字は半角数字に修正したいと考えています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

データの表現の幅が広そうなので、pandasのcontainsやextractを駆使するよりも[map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)や[applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)で関数を呼び出して柔軟に数値を抽出するのが望ましいと思います。

全角数字を半角に変換する処理のため、zenhanモジュールを使っています。
`pip install zenhan`でインストールするか、mojimojiなど他のモジュールを使う場合は読み替えてください。

要件を読み取れなかったので、下記のサンプルコードでは「徒歩」または「約」から始まる文字列のみ徒歩扱いで判定しています。
「１００分」や「東京駅から徒歩1分」は徒歩扱いになりませんので、必要に応じて`get_walk_time`関数のif文などを修正してください。

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import zenhan

def get_walk_time(s):
    s = zenhan.z2h(s)
    if not re.match('(徒歩|約)', s):
        return None
    m = re.search('(\d+)分', s)
    return m.group(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['徒歩４分', '2駅12分', '約5分', '１００分', '東京駅から徒歩1分']},
    index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

df["walk_time"] = df.x.map(get_walk_time)
print(df.walk_time) # [4, None, 5, None, None]
```

Comment: 思いもよらぬ、案を示してくださいまして、大変勉強になります。早速反映させたいと思います。

Comment: 下記の修正を反映させる方法を追加で示していただけるとありがたいです。「「１００分」や「東京駅から徒歩1分」は徒歩扱いになりませんので、必要に応じてget_walk_time関数のif文などを修正してください。」

Comment: 質問から要件を読み取れない私が思い付きで類例を挙げたものがコメントの2例です。徒歩分数と判断する要件によって修正方法が変わりますので、もし私の回答をうまく修正できずに困っている場合には詳細な要件と修正中のコードを提示する新しい質問を作成される方がよろしいかと存じます。私は特定の仕様を満たすよりも類似の質問者に幅広く役立つことを目的に回答しております。その旨をご理解いただきますと幸いです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。できましたら、書かせて頂きます。